# Program prints garbage upon EOF

Tags: c

I'm reading through the K&R book and implemented the 'copy' example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

All normal input appears to work correctly but when an EOF (^D) is entered the program prints infinite "�" characters and I must halt the program manually.

I have tried using `putchar(c);` as well as `printf("%c", c);` to the same effect.

Does anyone know the cause of this?

Comment: It should be `int c;`. Is this really from K&R as is?

Comment: This is correct and no, I copied it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `c` is of type `char`, an `int` value returned from `getchar` will be converted to the type `char` before it is compared to `EOF`.

Since the `EOF` is an in-band error mechanism, it has to be an error value that can be distinguished from all valid characters that could be returned. When you assign `EOF` to a `char` you discard information.

After executing:

```
char c = EOF;
```

the statement

```
c == EOF
```

is false.

Preserve the return type of `getchar` by doing:

```
int c;
```

instead of:

```
char c;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `int c` instead of `char c` should solve your issue